# How to explode an array into multiple columns in Spark Java

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, javadoc

I have the specific Dataframe

```
+-------+----------------------+
|BlockId|Entity_BlockNumberList|
+-------+----------------------+
|      1|      [[1, 4], [3, 5]]|
|      2|      [[1, 4], [3, 5]]|
|      3|      [[2, 4], [4, 4]]|
|      4|      [[2, 4], [4, 4]]|
|      5|      [[2, 4], [3, 5]]|
|      6|      [[3, 5], [5, 3]]|
|      7|      [[1, 4], [4, 4]]|
|      8|  [[3, 5], [4, 4], ...|
|      9|  [[1, 4], [2, 4], ...|
+-------+----------------------+
```

I want to create multiple columns for each element of the nested arrays in the 2nd Column
Something like that

```
BlockId | Entity_BlockNumberList | 1st Array | 2nd Array | ...
```

Something like explode but in Columns by using Javadoc
I have found this code on the internet

```
val numCols = df
  .withColumn("letters_size", size($"letters"))
  .agg(max($"letters_size"))
  .head()
  .getInt(0)

df
  .select(
    (0 until numCols).map(i => $"letters".getItem(i).as(s"col$i")): _*
  )
  .show()
```

which is in scala but i cant quite get how to do the select func especially the (0 until numCols) by using Java.

example:
input:

```
+---------+
|  letters|
+---------+
|[a, b, c]|
|[d, e, f]|
|     null|
+---------+
```

expected output:

```
+----+----+----+
|col0|col1|col2|
+----+----+----+
|   a|   b|   c|
|   d|   e|   f|
|null|null|null|
+----+----+----+
```

But not hardcoded because my arrays dont have the same length.

I tried that

```
df.selectExpr(df.select(
                expr("concat('struct(',concat_ws(',',transform(sequence(0,max(size(entities))-1),x -> concat('entities[',x,'] as col',x))),') as columns')")
                ).as(Encoders.STRING()).head()).show();
```

The output was the follow:

```
+------------+
|     columns|
+------------+
|    [1, 3,,]|
|    [1, 3,,]|
|    [2, 4,,]|
|    [2, 4,,]|
|    [2, 3,,]|
|    [3, 5,,]|
|    [1, 4,,]|
|[3, 4, 5, 6]|
|  [1, 2, 5,]|
+------------+
```

Comment: whats your expected output ?

Comment: @Srinivas i updated the question with sample input and sample expected output

Comment: spark version ??

Comment: @Srinivas 2.4.3 by using Java8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best I could do to achieve what I wanted that works and in nested arrays is do a for like that.

```
for (int i; i < numCols; i++) {
    df = df.withColumn("c" + i, df.col("entities").getItem(i));
}
```

The output:

```
+-----+------------+---+---+----+----+
|block|    entities| c0| c1|  c2|  c3|
+-----+------------+---+---+----+----+
|    1|      [1, 3]|  1|  3|null|null|
|    2|      [1, 3]|  1|  3|null|null|
|    3|      [2, 4]|  2|  4|null|null|
|    4|      [2, 4]|  2|  4|null|null|
|    5|      [2, 3]|  2|  3|null|null|
|    6|      [3, 5]|  3|  5|null|null|
|    7|      [1, 4]|  1|  4|null|null|
|    8|[3, 4, 5, 6]|  3|  4|   5|   6|
|    9|   [1, 2, 5]|  1|  2|   5|null|
+-----+------------+---+---+----+----+
```

Kinda worked for what i wanted to do next.

Answer (score 0):

Below Code will work in `scala` and also `java`

```
df.show(false)
+---------+
|letters  |
+---------+
|[a, b, c]|
|[d, e, f]|
|[]       |
+---------+
```

```
val colExpr = df.select(
        expr("concat('struct(',concat_ws(',',transform(sequence(0,max(size(letters))-1),x -> concat('letters[',x,'] as col',x))),') as columns')")
    )
    .as[String]
    .head
```

`colExpr` value will be `struct(letters[0] as col0,letters[1] as col1,letters[2] as col2) as columns`.

You can use this directly in `df.selectExpr(colExpr)` or you can also use like below.

```
df
.withColumn("columns",expr(colExpr))
.select($"letters",$"columns.*")
.show(false)

+---------+----+----+----+
|letters  |col0|col1|col2|
+---------+----+----+----+
|[a, b, c]|a   |b   |c   |
|[d, e, f]|d   |e   |f   |
|[]       |null|null|null|
+---------+----+----+----+
```

Comment: I tried this `df.selectExpr(df.select(
    expr("concat('struct(',concat_ws(',',transform(sequence(0,max(size(entities))-1),x -> concat('entities[',x,'] as col',x))),') as columns')")
    ).as(Encoders.STRING()).head()).show();`
But unfortunately the only this that happened is creating null values in the arrays with less than the max length.

Comment: can you update your question with the error  u are getting ??

Comment: also this solution may not work if you have list inside another lists (nested lists).. it will work only one level of list.